# Bluetooth between Mac OSX and Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, bluetooth, macosx

I want to share files via Bluetooth between a Mac OSX Mountain Lion and Ubuntu 12.04 but neither of the two can see/recognize each other.

Why did this happen? Is there a way to solve it?

Comment: Did you set the bluetooth on Ubuntu or Mac OS X to visible?

Comment: Do you have another device (perhaps portable like a phone) that you can use to verify the signal is strong enough over the distance you are trying to connect?

Comment: @lambda23 both turned on visibility/discover

Comment: @niallhaslam with phones both are ok.

Answer (score 0):

serial port opening for mac : [mac serial port](http://todbot.com/blog/2006/02/23/howto-mac-os-x-bluetooth-serial-port/)

for ubuntu : there is a program `sudo apt-get install blueman`

firts you have to setup blueman before do steps in link